# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1000.0 Mb R

Tags: r

I am trying to load a txt file into R and running into memory errors. When I checked the available memory it says 8072. I tried using fread and for some reason it shuts down.  The file has 785,000,000 records, 2 columns (1 GB). I am using an 8 GB machine running 64 bit. I have loaded far larger data sets than this in the past. Any recommendations?

```
memory.limit()

data<-read.table("volume.txt",sep="\t")[,c(ttl_units)]

require(data.table)
fread("shipped asin volume.txt",sep="\t", header= TRUE)-> pre
```

Comment: `format(object.size(rep(1,7.85e8)),units="Gb")` gives `5.8Gb` for me. That's just one column of 785M records, all 1s. Are you sure your calculation is right?

Comment: I will review the calculation and make sure I am doing it properly.  I ended up getting fread to work. I am not sure why it was shutting R down the first couple times I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to restart R

Also, AWAY FROM THIS, it is not recommended to use require when calling libraries because this means you are trying to load and if it loads it is equivalent to TRUE...