# R: Combine columns in matrix having same column name

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate

I have a large document-Term matrix.

I want to combine columns which with the same column name.

I have found someone asked the same problem and had work solution. [Combine columns in matrix having same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512441/combine-columns-in-matrix-having-same-column-name)

I have tried using the answer to do.

But R returns an error message to me.

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 49.3 Gb

```
#my large matrix
tf_mat <- as.matrix(dtm_title) %>%
          cbind(as.matrix(dtm_abstract)) %>%
          cbind(as.matrix(dtm_claim)) 

#Combine columns with same column name.
nms <- colnames(tf_mat)
tf_mat %*% sapply(unique(nms),"==", nms)

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 49.3 Gb
```

Is there any way to solve it? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Showing some sample data will get you more help.

Comment: There are lot of posts about solving the error you are facing. For example, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917532/r-memory-allocation-error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-75-1-mb) or [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169978/error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-1000-0-mb-r) .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your opinion.

I have tried use another way from [Combine columns in matrix having same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512441/combine-columns-in-matrix-having-same-column-name).

I think it's more suitable for my case, and don't take lot of time to execute.

```
nms <- colnames(tf_mat)
tf_mat_bind <- sapply(unique(nms), function(i)rowSums(tf_mat[, nms==i, drop=FALSE]))
```